# Trackpoint speed different from touchpad speed Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: gnome, 18.10

I am running Ubuntu 18.10 on my Thinkpad T450. It has both a touchpad and a trackpoint. However in the Gnome Settings I can only configure one speed value for the mouse. The problem is that the mouse and the touchpad have different sensitivities. The result is that either the trackpoint is way too fast, or the touchpad is way too slow to be useable.

Is there any way to configure the trackpoint speed separately from the touchpad speed?